# Finding the limit of a sequence?

Tags: limits

Is it possible to find the limit of the sequence defined by:
 $$a_n = \left(1+ \frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$
I have proved that it converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WolframAlpha comes up with this solution:
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2^n} \right)
&= \frac{(-1;\frac{1}{2})_\infty}{2} \\
&= 2.3842310290313\ldots
\end{align}
where $(a;q)_n$ is the $q$-Pochhammer symbol ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol)):
$$
(a;q)_n
= \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1 - a q^k)
$$

Comment: Thanks. How can I prove that the limit is not $e$?

Comment: You have $\ln(1+\frac{1}{2^n})<\frac{1}{2^n}$ for $n\geq 1$, hence if $P$ is your product you have $\ln(P)<\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n}=1$.